# Java 7 file deletion in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

```
    Path path = Paths.get("D:/tmp/a/aa/aaa");
    Files.delete(path);
    path = Paths.get("D:/tmp/a/aa");
    Files.delete(path);
```

Here is the exception i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: D:\tmp\a\aa
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:264)
  at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
  at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1077)
  at test.Test.main(Test.java:44)
```

though are no files/folders inside `aa` folder.

This behavior is observed when i visited the folder using windows explorer(Here `aa`) and moved to `D:\` root directory.

If i close the explorer widow, this program is working fine.

I know windows sometimes locks the folders, even in that case the exception message `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: D:\tmp\a\aa` seems to be wrong

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any hidden files in that folder?

Comment: `If i close the explorer widow, this program is working fine.` Explorer might be locking the directory. Feel free to raise a bug report with oracle regarding the message. It be worth mentioning that Java doesn't recognize any FS locking as it mostly OS independent.

Comment: @Hbcdev There are no hidden files/folders

Answer (score 3):

Yes the error message is wrong, but Windows will not let a file or folder be deleted it another process has a handle open on it.  This cannot be fixed from Java.

Answer (score 2):

Another tip, use "/" instead of "\\" as Java is supposed to be platform independant while "/" is recognised on both linux and windows.

Comment: or, even better, use `File.separator` to get the correct character for the current system

Comment: Since at least Windows NT back in the last millenium, Windows understands / in (most) path names just fine. 20 years later there are still people that write double backslashes - ugly!

Comment: @Wizardfan This should have been comment, not answer